# Will Clear Linux speed improvements be coming to Ubuntu?

Tags: performance

Intel's Clear Linux project has made a lot of performance improvements. Will some of those improvements be incorporated into upcoming Ubuntu releases?

Comment: If Intels Clear Linux performance enhancements has been committed to the kernel- and othere relevant repos, they will occur in Ubuntu at some point.

Comment: Unless the person at Intel responsible for this or the people from Phoronix are active on AU any answer is going to be a guess.

Comment: @Rinzwind may I ask what AU stands for?

Comment: That would be AskUbuntu

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding how a process like this works. From what I understand Clear Linux documents changes they have made to improve performance on their Github page. Wouldn't it be possible to at least partially bring those changes to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maybe.**

Most improvements, including performance improvements, come from the upstream projects, then to Debian, then to Ubuntu.

If Clear Linux is being a good citizen, like Fedora and Debian and others, passing their improvements upstream to application and kernel developers....And if the upstream developers feel that those changes are worthwhile....Then Debian and Ubuntu will receive those improvement in future upstream releases.

Ubuntu (and Debian) have a policy of keeping the number of patches and changes from stock upstream releases to a minimum due to the maintenance burden that patches create, so it's unlikely that developers will cherry-pick improvements directly from Clear's github.

Volunteers can help by spotting improvements in Clear that have not been upstreamed, helping that code reach the upstream developers, and helping test those changes in the upstream releases so it's solid by the time it gets incorporated into a future release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Can you say a bit more about how to help code reach upstream developers? I would like to find out more about how a process like this is structured and who the important stakeholders in the process are. I am still fairly new to the open source community and don't have a good understanding of how things work. Could I for example make some changes affecting Ubuntu systems and then send it as a suggestion to the team at Ubuntu/ Debian/ the Linux foundation? How does that usually work? If there are any resources available online, feel free to link them.

Comment: @phanky5 it would be better to address specific cases or improvements - a general explanation would run for many pages and have a thousand exceptions. In general, think of the Linux world as interlocking groups of cooperating volunteers. NOT companies - very different goals. In general, tested code (and the folks who write and test it) have the loudest voice. The way to get to know those folks with the most influence is to join projects that you are interested in, to contribute code, to triage bugs, to test new features, to write documentation, and to package for downstream distros.

Answer (score -1):

try xanmod it has most improvements like the clear linux kernel
check out this link:
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=xanmod-2020-kernel&num=1

Comment: This pretty good answer is flawed because it is a link only answer, and it has been flagged automatically by a review bot. If you don't care enough to explain your answer better than by only providing a link  it will most likely be deleted by reviewers.

Comment: I've run the xanmod kernel in arch and compared it to clear linux. My experience with clear linux is that it is more responsive and faster than xanmod. Even phoronix benchmarks show this. My metric is a little different. I type 100-120WPM. Even the slightest lag between when I touch the key and it is drawn on screen causes me headaches and frustration. ClearLinux is the first distro/kernel that I haven't had issues with.